# How to reverse-engineering by using ODI-SDK?

Tags: oracle, groovy, sdk, oracle-data-integrator

I try to use ODI-SDK with groovy scripting to automate reverse-engineering datastores to model. To do this, i used following script doStandardReverse() method, but nothing is happen. How can be possible, is there any other methods to do this.

```
import oracle.odi.domain.project.finder.IOdiProjectFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.model.finder.IOdiDataStoreFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.model.finder.IOdiModelFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.model.OdiModel
import oracle.odi.domain.model.OdiModel.ReverseObjectType
import oracle.odi.domain.project.finder.IOdiFolderFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.project.finder.IOdiUserProcedureFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.project.finder.IOdiKMFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.mapping.finder.IMappingFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.adapter.project.IKnowledgeModule.ProcessingType
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.finder.IOdiContextFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.finder.IOdiLogicalSchemaFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.finder.IOdiTechnologyFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiContext
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiTechnology
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiLogicalSchema
import oracle.odi.domain.model.OdiDataStore
import oracle.odi.domain.xrefs.expression.Expression
import oracle.odi.domain.xrefs.expression.Expression.SqlGroupType
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiProcedureLine.LogCounter
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiProcedureLineCmd
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiUserProcedure
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiUserProcedureLine
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiPackage
import oracle.odi.core.persistence.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition
import oracle.odi.core.service.reverse.ReverseService
import oracle.odi.domain.project.StepModel.ReverseModel

    def reversedatastore(model_id) {

      txnDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition()
      tm = odiInstance.getTransactionManager()
      tme = odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager()
      txnStatus = tm.getTransaction(txnDef)

      rs = new ReverseService()
      rm = rs.doStandardReverse(odiInstance, model_id, ReverseService.DataStoreSelection.ALL, null)

      tme.persist(rs)
      tm.commit(txnStatus)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need persist command. It will not work on that object.
Besides that, your code it's ok but it's a function. You need to call that function. I don't see any call of it.
Or, you can do it without a function.
The below code it's working.

```
import oracle.odi.domain.project.finder.IOdiProjectFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.model.finder.IOdiDataStoreFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.model.finder.IOdiModelFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.model.OdiModel
import oracle.odi.domain.model.OdiModelFolder
import oracle.odi.domain.model.OdiModel.ReverseObjectType
import oracle.odi.domain.project.finder.IOdiFolderFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.project.finder.IOdiUserProcedureFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.project.finder.IOdiKMFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.mapping.finder.IMappingFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.adapter.project.IKnowledgeModule.ProcessingType
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.finder.IOdiContextFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.finder.IOdiLogicalSchemaFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.finder.IOdiTechnologyFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiContext
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiTechnology
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiLogicalSchema
import oracle.odi.domain.model.OdiDataStore
import oracle.odi.domain.xrefs.expression.Expression
import oracle.odi.domain.xrefs.expression.Expression.SqlGroupType
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiProcedureLine.LogCounter
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiProcedureLineCmd
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiUserProcedure
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiUserProcedureLine
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiPackage
import oracle.odi.core.persistence.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition
import oracle.odi.core.service.reverse.ReverseService
import oracle.odi.domain.project.StepModel.ReverseModel

txnDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition()
tm = odiInstance.getTransactionManager()
tme = odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager()
txnStatus = tm.getTransaction(txnDef)

OdiModel srcModel = ((IOdiModelFinder)tme.getFinder(OdiModel.class)).findByCode("DL_ITM_SRC_AUTO");

//call reverse engeneering
rs = new ReverseService();

rm = rs.doStandardReverse(odiInstance, srcModel.getModelId(), ReverseService.DataStoreSelection.ALL, null);

println('Data Store/s created.');


tm.commit(txnStatus)
```